# Retrieving Hardware Interface Name from MAC or IP Address on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, cmd.exe

I have some proprietary software that proxies some ethernet-connected device IPs to software IPs.

In order to map the proxy IPs back to the N ethernet connections, I am ARP'ing the proxy, `Who has <IP>?` for the IP and MAC of the device proxied to the software defined IP.

Now, rather than parse `ipconfig` output and matching it against the IP, my thinking is there must be some straightforward command to fetch the plaintext name of the device associated with the MAC or IP address, such as:

```
> some-command <MACAddr|IPAddr>
"Ethernet-33"
```

How would I do this in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, such commands only exist for PowerShell:

- For IP addresses:

  ```
  (Get-NetIPAddress 10.20.30.40).InterfaceAlias
  ```
- For MAC addresses – in the Windows `AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF` format:

  ```
  (Get-NetAdapter | ? {$_.MacAddress -eq "AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF"}).Name
  ```